# What causes ViewWillLayoutSubviews and UpdateViewConstraints to be called?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I am modifying the priority of existing constraints for one of many views inside a UIScrollView. The result only changes the position of one of the subviews. All remaining subviews maintain their original size and position, and I am not modifying constraints involving them. I am incurring a layout pass on all subviews below the one I am modifying constraints on. Why is this happening?

Original question got little response, maybe because of the detail, but the code for how I'm setting up my constraints can be found there: [Scroll hesitation with floating view in UIScrollView using auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525706/scroll-hesitation-with-floating-view-in-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout)

I have three groups of constraints: ones that don't ever change, ones that apply to a subview that define where it lives in the scrollview relative to its siblings, and ones that apply to a subview that floats it out of the scrollview and pins it at the top of its parent.

To do this, I'm basically pinning the leading and trailing edges of each subview to the scrollview, and pinning each subviews top to the previous subview (or scrollview if first) and bottom to the next subview (or scrollview if last). These constraints have a priority of 750.

I'm also adding constraints to pin the leading, top and trailing edges of a subview to the scrollview's parent, to basically pull it from being inline and float it at the top. I'm also adding constraints to pin the previous and next siblings of the target subview to each other, accounting for the height of the target view. The intent with that is to keep everything in the same position. These constraints have a priority of 250.

When I decide I want a subview to float, I swap the priority of these constraints (only the ones that apply to the target subview, not all) so that the lower priority ones are applied. Specifically, I reduce the priority of the constraints that: pin the target subview's top edge to its previous sibling, the target subview's bottom edge to its next sibling and the target subview's leading and trailing edges to the scrollview. I increase the priority of the constraints that: pin the target subview's leading, top and trailing edges to the scrollview's parent.

Comment: Could you post some code sample? How are you updating the layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525706/scroll-hesitation-with-floating-view-in-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout

Comment: The closest I came to an explanation for this was that one of my child view controllers had some code that was updating constraints in viewWillLayoutSubviews. First, I didn't do anything for layout to be updated, so I'm still not sure why this method is being executed, but since I was modifying constraints, even though their values ended up the same, it explains why updateViewConstraints was being called. I worked around it by adding my own flag for when to layout views and update constraints and bypassing these calls to the super.